# Why is the Mandalorian's weapons locker on the Razor Crest so easy to open?

Tags: star-wars, the-mandalorian

In the first episode, the Mythrol the Mandalorian captured goes to use the vacc tube as a guise to poke around the ship and while snooping punches some buttons on a keypad. Doors on the opposite bulkhead open revealing a cabinet full of weapons. That might have been a fluke but it happens two other times in the series. When the Jawas strip the Razor Crest for parts they take all the weapons and when Din is transporting Ran's crew to the New Republic prison ship, Burg again punches the keypad and the weapons doors swing open.

I feel like it is actually a locker for the weapons for two reasons.  The first being that it is good practice to keep weapons locked up even if you are a bounty hunter and need quick access to them.  The Razor Crest is a pre-Empire military gunship so it may not originally be a locker, again for ease of access, but if you are transporting bounties you might want to change that.  The other reason is that both the Mythrol and Burg seem to punch more than a few buttons to open the weapons cache.  It crossed my mind that this could be a trap used by Din to see who he could trust and who he had to freeze in carbonite but this seems unlikely since it showed Greef Karga's goon unloading the bounties and they were all frozen but they were all criminals or at least had bounties out on them and thus all failed the test.

Why is the Mandalorian's weapon locker onboard the Razor Crest so easy to open?  If it is shown that the cabinet is not intended to guard the weapons and keep them from unapproved use then I will accept that as the answer.

Comment: Maybe I need to make an edit to the question.  Another reason it is probably a locker and that he does not need quick access is that he often keeps his disruptor rifle in the cabin with him.  He has a flamethrower, singing birds, and a cable launcher built into his armor which he never takes off.  He also has a blaster on his hip.  All that leads me to believe he has quick access to whatever firepower he needs.

Comment: The Mythrol and the Devoronian tap the 'keypad' 4 or 5 times.  Furthermore when the Devoronian opens the weapons cache Mando shuts it with his vambrace (wrist computer) this suggests he can open it without the wall mounted keypad too. (He has easy access)

Comment: RIP Razor Crest

Answer (score 3):

The answer is simple: He needs them to be ready at all times, and stowing them away or locking them would make it difficult to defend himself if needed. He does not expect anyone but himself and his captives to be aboard his ship, so why hide them? The Mandalorian himself answered your question: "Weapons are part of my religion"

Comment: He has many people besides himself and captives on his ship. Kuiil (IG-11 and blurgs), Cara Dune, Greef Karga, and not just allies, he leaves the Razor Crest to be repaired on Tatooine and he transports Ran's crew who is openly hostile to him. Also if its for ease of access why not a big red button that says "OPEN" instead there are always multiple touches on the keypad.

Comment: I'm saying that he does not expect people besides himself and captives on his ship BEFORE the events of the series, which is when he would have obtained the Razorcrest and programmed it. The events of the series are the last things he would have expected to happen to him, and he wouldn't have had the time or resources during the series to hide his weapons locker or add a more advanced security system. Also, he is clearly VERY uncomfortable with having the people you mentioned on his ship BECAUSE his weapons were so accessible (and also because he didn't want them to discover The Child)

Answer (score 1):

Why would he lock the weapons away? He (and maybe some of his allies) are the only ones on the ship. The bounties are frozen and can't threat him, there's no use to lock them away.

Assume you have weapons in your house. You only have guests in your house you know are loyal to you (or frozen) and know how to handle weapons. Locking them up properly only takes time to access them in time of need and doesn't give you any advantage. They're stored out of reach of anybody simply snooping around and no one can access them without clicking the right button on the keypad. That's enough security for somebody travelling alone or with people he trusts.

Comment: He does have a child on there.  That's the main reason I lock mine up.  That and so they don't get stolen by Jawas.

Comment: I think he's not used to have a child in his ship. Furthermore, Baby Yoda is way to small to reach either the keypad or the weapons and not agile enough (or so it would seem) to climb up there. So, his usual passengers are frozen. As for the Jawas: they took his ship apart. No matter what security lock he had, they would've reached them. And if they get into the ship when it's locked, a weapons locker wont stop them. So, it's still: doesn't really do any good and would cost him time in case he needs the weapon urgently...

Comment: Yeah you're right.  I was just trying to be a little humorous.  Your answer might be right too but I'm still hoping someone has a canon source to back it up.

Comment: Sorry, difficult to read irony without the tone ^^. If there is a lore explanation, it would certainly interest me quite a bit why cause it was always "obvious" to me... But then again, that's why we are here.

Answer (score -2):

There's something we're missing on these responses... why the hell would you need to have quick access to your weapons on a suposedly secure environment where there can only be allies and/or frozen targets?

My guess is that the this not a military ship, so it hasn't a secure space for weapon storage, at least not as a default option. So to speak.

Comment: According to [StarWars.com](https://www.starwars.com/databank/razor-crest) it was a pre-Empire military ship used to patrol locally.

Comment: That's a comment and not an answer.

Comment: In the First episode of The Mandalorian, he decided not to freeze his bounty because the man was being relatively cooperative. However, the target attempts to escape, which would be a situation in which Mando would need quick access to his weapons. Another situation would be when the Ravanak attacked the Razor Crest from under the ice (ch. 1). Had Mando been unable to reach his weapons quickly, his entire ship would have been devoured. Also, if an enemy were to follow Mando to his ship (as Greef Karga did in Chapter 3: the Sin) Then Mando would need his weapons to fight/escape. That's why.